# Cannot get onClick function to work on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to push the body content to the right, however, for whatever reason I can't seem to get my body variable to work with the onClick function at all. I thought that only '(document.body)' would work with on('click', function()) but that doesn't seem to be case? Please see code below along with jsfiddle, thanks in advance for your insights!

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jhh7p8nj/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $toggle =  $('#toggle'),
    $body = $(document.body),
    $sidebar = $('.sidebar');

$toggle.on('click', function(){
    $sidebar.toggleClass('sidebarShow');
  $body.addClass('pushRight')
 });
  });
```

Comment: try using $(body) instead of document.body -- document.body is what you would use without using jQuery.

Comment: Your Fiddle seems to work though..

Comment: Use `$('body')` and use `margin-left:250px;` instead of using `left:250px` on the body. EDIT: or use what @MarekJanoud suggests below.

Comment: add `.pushRight { position: relative; }`

Comment: Might I suggest using a wrapper `div` rather than moving the *entire* body element, though? You're not simply moving the *content* of the body here, but the *entire* body element. Wrap all of the content of the body in something like `<div id="wrapper"></div>` `#wrapper { position: relative;left:250px;}`

Comment: thanks guys... it isn't really moving on the first click the way i intended however. if i click the button, it moves the sidebar and other div together... i am trying to push only the content on the right away from the left...   if i change to margin-left it works as i intended if i click the button twice..

Comment: @spectre-d, thanks.. however, in the actual design i'm using there's a topbar that i want to move as well.  most other people i know move the entire body if they are doing something similar, so this is where the confusion lies for me.  the sidebar is hidden, until toggled, and since it needs to be in the 'wrapper' div of the design, would it not need to be moved as well?

Comment: @user2004758, this isn't the best way to do it, but just to show you there are "better" alternatives: https://jsfiddle.net/jhh7p8nj/4/ If your sidebar is hidden, and should push the content to the right, set it's display to `none` initially, and onclick, the `sidebarshow` class should change the display type to `inline-block`, set `.main` to inline block as well and it will be pushed to the right. If these two divs are at the top, then all content within them should be moved accordingly. Think of these as two sections "sidebar" and "main wrapper".

Comment: @spectre-d, thanks spectre! i will try it that way and report back.  appreciate your help (:.

Comment: When you figure it out, please consider adding an answer and accepting it to assist other users who may experience a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the class

```
.pushRight {
  left: 250px;
}
```

Which isn't going to do anything. If you change it to

```
.pushRight {
position:relative;     
left: 250px;
}
```

That should work (or at least it does in jsFiddle)

But like @spectre-d said, a wrapper would be much better than moving the entire `body`.